# apt-get has unmet dependencies, but apt-get -f install doesn't solve problem

Tags: install, apt

I've tried to install emacs on Ubuntu server 64bit 11.04, but it's complaining about emacs23-common. If I do:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I still see the same problem:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs23-common_23.2+1-7ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can  I solve this situation?

Comment: The actual error message from `dpkg` should be a few lines above the "Errors were encountered ..." line.  Can you please post it? It will help figuring out what's actually wrong.

Comment: It would also help to post the output of `apt-cache policy packagenames` where packagenames are the relevent packages (target/dependencies etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

your local repository may be out of date

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated in the comments, more information is needed to accurately diagnose your problem.

I may be misinformed, but my understanding is that aptitude has better dependency resolution than regular old apt-get. You could try aptitude?

Comment: The error message refers to something that `dpkg` didn't like during the installation of package `emacs23-common`.  So it's not dependency resolution that is failing, it's the actual installation of the package.