# Ubuntu upgrades blocked due to insufficient disk space for linux-image

Tags: kernel, apt

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS on a desktop at my home that I was intending to turn into a server, but I never really did much on it. I then decided to turn it into a send-only SMPT server, but when I tried `sudo apt-get install postfix` to install postfix, I got this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-42-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-56-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-56-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-vivid : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-56-generic but it is not going to be installed
                             Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried running sudo apt-get -f install, but that didn't work:

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.19.0-56-generic_3.19.0-56.62~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.19.0-56-generic (3.19.0-56.62~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-56-generic_3.19.0-56.62~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-56-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-56-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                          dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-56-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-56-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-56-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-56-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic_3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic (3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic_3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                          dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-56-generic_3.19.0-56.62~14.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic_3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried installing other packages and the error persists across all uses of `apt-get install`.

I also followed the instructions at [apt-get has unmet dependencies, but apt-get -f install doesn't solve problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15810/apt-get-has-unmet-dependencies-but-apt-get-f-install-doesnt-solve-problem) to run `sudo apt-get clean`, but that still didn't solve my problem.

So what is wrong? What must I do to get `apt-get` working again?

I do not know much about this issue, so I may not have provided all the necessary information. Please comment if I need to add more.

Comment: Please paste the output of `apt-cache policy` and `apt-cache policy postfix linux-image-extra-3.19.0-42-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-56-generic linux-image-generic-lts-vivid`, please. You've got a "no space on device" for `/boot`, so that may be part of your problem. Check availability of space on `/boot` or the filesystem containing it..

Comment: The primary issue appears to be `No space left on device`: you will need to free some disk space in order to continue

Comment: @steeldriver There also appears to be a separate apt dependency problem.

Comment: @FaheemMitha No, the dependency problem is a consequence of the disk space problem (B is to be installed, B depends on A, A can't be installed due to insufficient disk space, so the installation of B fails due to a dependency error).

Comment: Yes, it must be a `/boot` problem. I put it on a separate primary partiton and allocated just 200 Mb. But might I ask, why is this adding content to `/boot`? I thought `/boot` just stored the boot files and didn't get more files added to it, but clearly I am terribly wrong...